# Caught signal 15 When shutting down

Tags: 11.10, 3g, usb-modem

When I doing shutdown , my laptop freezing after the next lines:
Network-manager: Caught signal 15
umount /run/lock is not mounted

Into /run/lock I can found ttyUSB0 file.
What I can do in this situation?

Also I should add that ttyUSB0 - this is my 3G modem.

Comment: One more addition: I solve this problem by using hibernate.
But really this can't solve my problem fully. 
So what is the difference between shut down and hibernate (I mean only stopping network manager).

Answer (score 1):

type ls -l /var

Tell me if their are symbolic links set up on the directory "run" and the directory "lock"
There needs to be symbolic links from /run to /var/run and /run/lock to /var/run/lock
If there is not type the following commands:

sudo ln -s /run /var/run
sudo ln -s /run/lock /var/lock

Comment: ls -l /var can find that links:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 2012-02-15 15:40 lock -> /run/lock 

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     4 2012-02-15 15:40 run -> /run